# Solr Error Uploading File using ContentStreamUpdateRequest

Tags: solr, solrj

I am using the following solrj code for to index the document.

```
     ContentStreamUpdateRequest req = new ContentStreamUpdateRequest("/update/extract");
     ContentStreamBase.FileStream fs = new FileStream(new File(filename));
     req.setWaitSearcher(false);
     req.setMethod(METHOD.POST );
     //req.addFile(new File(filename), null);
     req.addContentStream(fs);
     req.setParam("literal.id", filename);
     req.setParam("resource.name", filename);
     //req.setParam("uprefix", "attr_");
     //req.setParam("fmap.content", "attr_content");
     //req.setAction(AbstractUpdateRequest.ACTION.COMMIT, true, true);
     NamedList<Object> result = this.mHttpSolrClient.request(req);
```

However, I am always getting an SolrException right after the request, which says

```
4767120 [qtp559670971-21] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor  [   test] – [test] webapp=/solr path=/update/extract params={waitSearcher=false&resource.name=/tmp/RUNNING.txt&literal.id=/tmp/RUNNING.txt&wt=javabin&version=2} {} 0 6
4767121 [qtp559670971-21] ERROR org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  [   test] – org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=/tmp/RUNNING.txt] Error adding field 'stream_size'='null' msg=For input string: "null"
```

I am using the latest version of solr 5.1.0. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you mark "stream_size" as a required field in your configurations?  Because if you did, and then you're not setting it, that could be the problem.

Comment: Josh Edwards in where do I add that? When I created the core/collections I just did `./bin/solr create -c test`

Comment: You can see your configurations that include your fields under {your collection folder}/conf/schema.xml .  Look to see what fields are defined.  There will be lines that look somewhat like this: <field name="key" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" /> .   Based on the error, I was guessing there might be one called "stream_size" which is set to required="true", but isn't populated by your code above.

Comment: the strange thing is that, stream_size gets added when using solr's own post tool.
Using `./bin/post -c test *.txt` it works. 
Strange enough I checked the packets headers and any POST packet sent through solrj is missing content.length in the HTTP header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue by setting the HttpSolrClient to enable multi part post. Ask me how, I don't know. Solr documentation just does not explain things well.

`mHttpSolrClient.setUseMultiPartPost(true);`

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you got a solution? I add the method call. But it don't work. Thanks for response.